# Where is the message center on Moto G?

Tags: sms, motorola-moto-g

I have a Moto G and I am not able to send messages, not able to find message centre. Where is the message centre?

Answer (score 6):

Summarized from [Motorola forum](https://forums.motorola.com/posts/df1d1e75b8), Moto G and Moto X are designed in such a way that it will take the message center number automatically from the Saved configuration of the SIM. Try changing the SIM from Slot 1 to Slot 2. Save and set as default for newly received configuration settings.

You can try the following method by [SmaRkieS on Android Geeks](http://www.android.gs/change-message-centre-number-from-any-android-based-smartphone/):

> Dial *#*#4636#*#*.
>
> You will get a menu. From that, select Phone Information. You will find
>   a setting "SMSC". Refresh it. It is most likely to retrieve the
>   message center number from your operator (or call your operator, and
>   get the message center number, and then update in this field), then the
>   problem should be resolved!